# Zendesk Can I add chat without setting up 'Feedback Tab'?

Tags: php, zendesk

I am using API to create tickets, and I want chat on same page.
But problem to enable chat, I need to setup Feedback Tab, so form from feedback tab also start showing up.
So I want to implement only chat which is going to separate/not embed  from feedback tab is that possible? if yes how?
If no how can I customize Feedback Tab to not to show create ticket form and only show chat with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for same, might be helpful to someone we can use only chat without **Feedback Tab** using following URL

```
https://{domain}.zendesk.com/chat?user[name]=test%20e&user[email]=test@test.com
```

You can also add other fields like follows

```
https://{domain}.zendesk.com/chat?utf8=✓&authenticity_token=secret_token=&dropboxID=007&dropboxLocale=1&user[name]=Test&user[email]=r@r.com&chat[subject]=test sub
```